# How can we select a row in datatable builded with ngx-formly

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-datatable, ngx-formly

```
File contain data with ngx-formly
```

I have to make an API call from backend, actually a  delete call. For this case i need to get the details from a row that i have to select.

In this case i need to get ID for example from selected row.

```html
          fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
            {
              key: 'investments',
              type: 'repeat',
              templateOptions: {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by adding 
 (select)="to.selectFN($event)"

like below

```html
<ngx-datatable
      #table
      class="bootstrap"
      
      (select)="to.selectFN($event)"
```